# Endomorphism ring of a generator-cogenerator over acyclic algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be an acyclic quiver algebra, $M$ a generator-cogenerator and $B=End_A(M)$.

Questions:

1. Does $B$ have finite global dimension?
2. Does $B$ have finite global dimension in case $M=A \oplus D(A)$?
3. Does $B$ have finite global dimension in case $M$ is a precluster tilting module in the sense of https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870816315055 (which is equivalent to $M$ being cluster tilting).